# Check format of text entered in NSTextField

Tags: objective-c, formatting, nstextfield

I've subclassed `NSTextField` and need to check that the text entered into it is in the format of either *00:00:00* or *0:00:00* with `textDidEndEditing`. I was about to go to regEx route but have read advice suggesting otherwise. Is there a more straightforward way of accomplishing this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would go the regex route. It offers a *lot* more flexibility in the end. `NSPredicate` just chills me to the bone.

Comment: What are your reasons for not wanting to use the most popular and arguably easy method to verify your text?

Comment: I have none other than reading advice to use `NSPredicate` and that regex isn't fully integrated into cocoa. I'm more familiar (but still rusty) with regex and was checking what the most straightforward way of accomplishing my goal was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're wanting to use `NSPredicate`, then you can simulate the use of regex by doing something like:

```
+(BOOL)text:(NSString*)content passesRegex:(NSString*)regex {
    NSPredicate* regextest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                              @"SELF MATCHES %@", regex];

    return ([regextest evaluateWithObject:content] == YES);
}
```